# visibilitychange event fires off in multiple home screen links after returning to one of them

Tags: javascript, ios

I have some home screen links whose only purpose is to launch an iOS app with a specific parameter. It was noticed that after opening multiple home screen links like that and later on returning to one of them would execute calls from all the home screen links that were opened. The desired effect would be to execute call only from the single home screen link that the user returned to.

I'm testing on iOS 13.2, but the issue was discovered on iOS 13.1.2. The home screen links themselves are base64 encoded data urls.

This is main Javascript code from home screen link:

```
// id is injected for every home screen link
const link = 'mycustomapp://{{id}}';

init();

/** Returns true if user came from ios homescreen. */
function fromIOSHomeScreen() {
    return window.navigator.standalone;
}

function init() {
    if (fromIOSHomeScreen()) {
        registerVisibilityChange();
        openApp();
    } else {
        showAddToHomescreenPopup();
    }
}

function registerVisibilityChange() {
    /***
     * Event listener added to fix a bug with app reopening.
     *
     * Without it, redirect was firing only on initial opening of the home screen link.
     * After returning to the home screen link the user was not being redirected anymore.
     */
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
        if (!document.hidden) {
            openApp();
        }
    });
}

function openApp() {
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

It seems like `visibilitychange` event listener triggers on multiple home screen links when user reopens one of them. The desire is to have only one `visibilitychange` listener to trigger in this situation.